# Python: loop para "clipar" (winsorizing) dados numéricos em um dataframe, atribuindo o resultado a um dicionário

Tags: pandas

O que está errado neste código?

```
#calculando retornos diários máximos e mínimos:

max_std = 3
max = {}
min = {}
retornos_stds = retornos_dia.std()
retornos_med = retornos_dia.mean()

for acao in acoes:
    max[acao] = retornos_med[acao] + max_std * retornos_stds[acao]
    min[acao] = retornos_med[acao] - max_std * retornos_stds[acao]
```

até aqui não há problema, os máximos e mínimos de cada ação são calculados normalmente e armazenados nos dicionários "max" e "min"

```
#clipando:
retorno_clipado = {}

for acao in acoes:
    for contar,r in enumerate(retornos_dia[acao]):         
        if r > max[acao]:
            retorno_clipado[acao][contar] = max[acao]
        elif r < min[acao]:
            retorno_clipado[acao][contar] = min[acao]
        else:
            retorno_clipado[acao][contar] = retornos_dia[acao][contar]

retorno_clipado
```

aqui ocorre o problema, o seguinte erro é retornado:

---

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-fd5fc22b112d> in <module>
      8             retorno_clipado[acao][contar] = min[acao]
      9         else:
---> 10             retorno_clipado[acao][contar] = retornos_dia[acao][contar]
     11 
     12 retorno_clipado

KeyError: 'PETR3'
```

'PETR3' é o primeiro elemento de *acoes*

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema:

```
#clipando:
retorno_clipado = retornos_dia
for acao in acoes:
    for contar,r in enumerate(retornos_dia[acao]):         
        if r > max[acao]:
            retorno_clipado[acao][contar] = max[acao]
        elif r < min[acao]:
            retorno_clipado[acao][contar] = min[acao]

retorno_clipado
```

Em vez de criar retorno_clipado como um dicionario vazio, o criei como uma cópia do dataframe original, que quero "clipar".

Aparentemente o problema aparecia ao tentar atribuir um valor a uma posição de uma lista dentro de um dicionário (como valor de uma chave) que ainda não tem a lista ou a posição ou a chave definidos:

```
teste = {}
teste['PETR3'][3] = 0.1
```

Com esse código temos o mesmo erro reportado acima. Por tentativa e erro descobri que conseguimos indexar dessa forma tanto para ler de uma lista dentro de um dicionário quanto para escrever numa lista dentro de um dicionário **DESDE QUE a lista e a posição já existam**. O que não é possível é escrever numa posição de uma lista que ainda não existe dentro dicionário usando a mesma indexação. Exemplo:

```
dicionario = {'chave1': 'gato','chave2': 'cachorro','chave3':['coelho1','coelho2','coelho3']}
dicionario['chave3'][1]
```

retorna 'coelho2'

```
dicionario['chave3'][1] = 'raposa'
print (dicionario)
```

retorno {'chave1': 'gato', 'chave2': 'cachorro', 'chave3': ['coelho1', 'raposa', 'coelho3']}

Já este:

```
dicionario['chave3'][4] = 'coelho4'
print (dicionario)
```

retorno Erro, pois a posição 4 da lista que é o valor da 'chave3' não existe